# Reset API key and secret key twitter in orange 3

Tags: api, twitter, orange

I am using orange 3 for crawling data from twitter. Maybe I entered the wrong API key and secret key. the remark is api error: 401 unauthorized. When I open twitter api key back in orange 3, bearer token always appears. when I fill in, the result is still an error. please help, thank you.

how to reset API key and secret key in widget twitter in orange 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.